# How to export a query to excel using Python?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, xlsx

I have been trying to loop through a list as a parameter for a query from database, and convert it into xlsx format, using pyodbc, pandas, xlsxwriter modules.

However, the message below keeps on appearing despite a process of trial and error: 
The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query.

Could this have something to do with the query itself or the module 'pandas'?

Thank you.

This is for exporting a query result to an excel spreadsheet using pandas and pyodbc, with python 3.7 ver.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd 

#Database Connection
conn = pyodbc.connect(driver='xxxxxx', server='xxxxxxx', database='xxxxxx',
                      user='xxxxxx', password='xxxxxxxx')

cursor = conn.cursor()

depts = ['Human Resources','Accounting','Marketing']

query = """
                           SELECT *
                           FROM device ID 
                           WHERE
                           Department like ?
                           AND
                           Status like 'Active'
                           """

target = r'O:\\Example'

today = target + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d')

if not os.path.exists(today):
    os.mkdir(today)

for i in departments:
    cursor.execute(query, i)
    #workbook = Workbook(today + os.sep + i + 'xlsx')
    #worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    P_data = pd.read_sql(data, conn)
    P_data.to_excel(today + os.sep + i + 'xlsx')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read data into a dataframe using pandas.read_sql(), pandas expects the first argument to be a query to execute (in string format), *not* the results from the query.

Instead of your line:

```
P_data = pd.read_sql(data, conn)
```

You'd want to use:

```
P_data = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
```

And to filter out the departments, you'd want to serialize the list into SQL syntax string:

```
depts = ['Human Resources','Accounting','Marketing']

# gives you the string to use in your sql query:
depts_query_string = "('{query_vals}')".format(query_vals="','".join(depts))
```

To use the new SQL string in your query, use str.format:

```
query = """
                           SELECT *
                           FROM device ID 
                           WHERE
                           Department in {query_vals}
                           AND
                           Status like 'Active'
                           """.format(query_vals=depts_query_string)
```

All together now:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd 

#Database Connection
conn = pyodbc.connect(driver='xxxxxx', server='xxxxxxx', database='xxxxxx',
                      user='xxxxxx', password='xxxxxxxx')

cursor = conn.cursor()

depts = ['Human Resources','Accounting','Marketing']

# gives you the string to use in your sql query:
depts_query_string = "('{query_vals}')".format(query_vals="','".join(depts))

query = """
                            SELECT *
                            FROM device ID 
                            WHERE
                            Department in {query_vals}
                            AND
                            Status like 'Active'
                            """.format(query_vals=depts_query_string)

target = r'O:\\Example'

today = target + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d')

if not os.path.exists(today):
    os.mkdir(today)

for i in departments:
    #workbook = Workbook(today + os.sep + i + 'xlsx')
    #worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    P_data = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
    P_data.to_excel(today + os.sep + i + 'xlsx')
```

Comment: This ignores the parameter required for the query, and it'd help if you showed how this changed OP's code (i.e. the redundant lines that could be removed)

Comment: Thank you for a swift response! It is great but I still need to use the list above(depts) to filter out the result.

Comment: @asongtoruin, thanks for the feedback I updated my answer.

Comment: @SangsooHa No problem!  Sorry I missed that part.  I updated my answer for you.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your query sorted, you can just load directly into a dataframe with the following command.

```
P_data = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
P_data.to_excel('desired_filename.format')
```